# How to unit test with SuperTest to post files with multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer, supertest, multer-s3

Right now, I have a form which submits an array of image 'files' using multer and aws-S3 and receives the following type of object for processing in the POST controller:

```
files: [
{
  fieldname: 'uploaded',
  originalname: 'test.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  size: 1407923,
  bucket: 'mybucket',
  key: '2343.jpg',
  acl: 'public-read',
  contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
  contentDisposition: null,
  storageClass: 'STANDARD',
  serverSideEncryption: null,
  metadata: null,
  location: 'https://mybucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/12144etest.jpg',
  etag: '"7503d8c8f9cdca"',
  versionId: undefined
}
```

]

How can I post an mock object like this with supertest? Right now I have this but I'm getting a 500 internal server error so clearly I'm doing something wrong:

```
let res = await api
  .post("/login")
  .send({"username" : "user", "password": "pass"})

await supertest(app)
  .post('/upload')
  .attach('files', 'test.jpg')
  .set('cookie', res.headers['set-cookie'])
```

Comment: In addition of missing a double quote, You are attaching a string as test file not a real image.

Comment: ah fixed the quote. I'm not sure what you mean by real image? the image i'm attaching is a real one in the same directory as the test called 'test.jpg'

Comment: Could you provide error log?

Answer (score 2):

```js
await supertest(app)
  .post('/upload')
  .attach('files', `${__dirname}/test.jpg`) // added __dirname here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using full path of file will fix your problem.